# Why does this not override the class constructor?

Tags: java

```
public class ExtAA extends AA {
   static int iTime;

   public static void main(String argv[]) {
       ExtAA d = new ExtAA();
       d.func(iTime);
   }

   public static void func(int iTime) {
      System.out.println(iTime);
   }

   public ExtAA() { }
}



class AA {
   public AA() { System.out.println("AA");  }
}
```

prints:

```
AA
0
```

I would have expected `public ExtAA() { }` to override the constructor for `AA` and thus not print AA, just `0`. Could someone explain in what way I am wrong, and if I'd want to override the constructor how could I ?

P.S. It is completely possible that my question is stupid, but I don't get what public `ExtAA()` { } should or could do. This was at a test, I messed up and I'd like to know what's actually happening (yes, I did go into debug and go over it step by step, I just don't know why `new ExtAA` uses `AA` instead of it's own defined constructor)

Comment: Constructors cannot be overridden, instead they are called in hierarchy from top to bottom ie from Object class till last class in the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constructor of super class in Java is always called. You can't stop that. You can just control which constructor is called if there are more of them.

Please consider reading some basic tutorial of Java, this is elementary thing of Java OOP.

Implicitly your constructor looks like this:

```
public ExtAA() {
    super(); // Constructor of super class call, always first line of code in child constructor
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagine if you could skip a constructor from a base. It could leave the parent part of an object in an extremely unstable state.

Think about a situation where a base class does some kind of meaningful initialization in the constructor. If that doesn't get done, then suddenly the base class part of your object is in crazy-town. This is almost certainly why Java decided to work like this.

As a super trivial example, imagine if you had a SortedArrayList class that extends ArrayList. If SortedArrayList somehow didn't call any of the ArrayList constructors, do you think the internals of the object would make sense? Somewhere there would be a nulled out data structure meaning things would crash and burn. In certain situations it might make sense to override a constructor, but apparently the Java people felt that the risk of accidentally doing it wasn't worth the ability (and it *very* rarely makes sense in a well designed class graph -- if the child class doesn't depend on the base class in some way, then why is it a child class to begin with?).

Answer (score 2):

An object has the fields of its own class plus all fields of its parent class, grandparent class, all the way up to the root class Object. It's necessary to initialize all fields, therefore all constructors must be called! The Java compiler automatically inserts the necessary constructor calls in the process of constructor chaining, or you can do it explicitly.